# Variables lost outside loop

Tags: bash

I am trying to backup my DB using mysqldump, while ignoring some tables defined in a variable, but while looping, I got the last table name, it was overridden, how can I store tables inside a variable and get them after the loop?

```
ignoreTables=('visitors_15012016 visitors_Original')

for line in $ignoreTables
do
echo 'mysqldump --ignore-table='$line
done

echo 'li '$line // here I got "visitors_Original"

mysqldump --log-error=/var/log/mysql-dump/dump.log -u USER -pPASSWD DBName $line | bzip2 > /path2file/file.sql.bz2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For 2 variables, why you don't just write two times the line in the script ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, along with your script. When you use a temporary variable *line* and use it to iterate through you variable *ignoreTables* it is basic logic of for loop that the last element will remain in the iterator. 
One thing you can do if you want some selected tables only to be dumped in a file. Create a file, put all the required tables in it.Then

```
for i in $(cat list_of_required_tables.txt);do
mysqldump --log-error=/var/log/mysql-dump/dump.log -u USER -pPASSWD DBName $i >> mysql_dump.sql
done
```

or if you think that the list of tables which should be ignored is quite a few, then you can create a list of all tables and then create a list of tables which you don't need. then use below loop.

```
for i in $(cat list_of_tables_not_required.txt);do
sed -i "/$i/d" list_of_all_tables.txt
done
```

then use the first code.